# Replacing/Inserting Timestamp in a File

Tags: regex, linux, file, replace, sed

I have a JSON file which contains the data in the following format. I'm writing indexing task for druid to ingest the data. It refusing because of the timestamp (event_time).

Is there a way to convert the event_time value to **2016-11-30T23:59:53.654Z** from **2016-11-30 23:59:53.654000**?

JSON File:

`{"app":14232,"device_carrier":"airtel","$schema":10,"city":"Bellary","user_id":"234293","uuid":"1d5b5328-b729-11e2-a0e5-22340a56812f","event_time":"2016-11-30 23:59:53.654000","platform":"Android","os_version":"4.4.2","insider_id":3426766963,"processed_time":"2016-12-01 00:00:05.429064","user_creation_time":"2015-12-14 18:34:04.632000","version_name":"2.08","ip_address":"117.266.132.112","paying":"true","dma":null,"user_properties":{"[SauceFlyer] campaign":"N\/A","[SauceFlyer] media source":"Chemical"},"client_upload_time":"2016-12-01 00:00:03.982000","$insert_id":"e43b2a4d-072f-2322-bd74-6bdb0b2e1f63","event_type":"Search","library":"insider-android\/2.9.2","device_type":"Micromax Owen Nitro","device_manufacturer":"Micromax","start_version":"1.57","location_lng":null,"server_upload_time":"2016-12-01 00:00:04.230000","event_id":286,"location_lat":null,"os_name":"android","insider_event_type":null,"device_brand":"Micromax","groups":{},"event_properties":{"Search Query":"clutches for women"},"data":{},"device_id":"ff71c4f0-81b8-4a44-8db1-1555e22f6761R","language":"English","device_model":"Micromax A310","country":"India","region":"Karnataka","adid":null,"session_id":1480550372776,"device_family":"Micromax Phone","idfa":null,"client_event_time":"2016-11-30 23:59:53.406000"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is in `input.json` and you want to do it with sed:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) \([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{3\}/\1T\2Z/g' input.json
```

(Yeah, I agree that it is ugly.)
It replaces *all* timestamps in your input, though, assuming that is what you want. If not, you have to extend the regex to also match the key before it.

An equivalent perl one-liner "for better readability":

```
cat input.json | perl -p -e 's/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})\d{3}/\1T\2Z/g'
```

Comment: How can we include key before that timestamp. for example event_time with sed?

Comment: Thanks Jan. Got it. 

sed 's/"event\_time":.\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) \([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{3\}/"event\_time":\1T\2Z/g' sample.json

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with sed(because year, month, days, hours, minutes and seconds are not only `[0-9]` digits):

```
$ sed 's/\([12][0-9]\{3\}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\) \([0-2][0-9]\(:[0-5][0-9]\)\{2\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)000/\1T\2Z/' <<< "2016-11-30 23:59:53.654000"
2016-11-30T23:59:53.654Z
```